# Inherit interface fields in implemented types graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I have a interface

```
interface Book {
 field1: String
 field2: String
 field3: String
 # it has 10 fields
}
```

and i want to implement it in 10 different types. how can i avoid coping all the fields and pasting into types which implements that interface

for example, can i do something like this:

```
type textBook implements Book{
  ...Book Fields
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax to help you avoid repetition. If an interface defines a field, each type that implements the interface must explicitly define that field. At best, if you're using `graphql-tag` to create your type definitions, you can use interpolation to make things drier, but I personally don't think the decreased readability of your code is worth it. It also means you can't put your type definitions in separate `.graphql` files.

```
const sharedFields = `
  a: String
  b: String
`
const typeDefs = gql`
  type A {
    ${sharedFields}
  }
  type B {
    ${sharedFields}
  }
`
```

If the shared fields are related conceptually, you can also consider making them a separate type.

```
interface Book {
  bookFields: BookFields
}

type BookFields {
  field1: String
  field2: String
  field3: String
  # etc.
}
```